# When multiple clients push to same remote repository, how does git deal with concurrency issues?

Tags: git, concurrency

For each http request, a separate process `git-http-backend` runs on the server side.

When multiple clients push to same remote repository, what does it do to handle concurrency issues?

For example, does it create lock file and what the name is?

Note: Remote repository is bare.

Answer (score 2):

In the same manner as if invoked via SSH -- see the [update_ref function in refs.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/tree/refs.c?id=v1.8.2.1#n2453). The actual implementation of the locking mechanism lives in the [lock_file function in lockfile.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/tree/lockfile.c?id=v1.8.2.1#n125), and yes, it creates a `.lock` file in there. Under the hood, it's done via the `O_EXCL` option to `open()`.

Comment: It seems git does not wait for a moment before saying lock failed. User needs to retry?

Comment: The ref update shall be rather fast -- it's basically just writing 20 bytes into a single file. I've never read a complaint about this, but I'm not involved in git development, either.

Comment: Does the OS guarantee that writing 20 bytes is fast enough?

Comment: I'm not sure what is your point here -- yes, the locking can fail. In that case, your push fails, and the user will have to try it once again. There's no race, no conflict to solve, no data corruption. Even ff git tried locking a few times in a row, where would you draw the line on when to give up? Shall it try three times? Shall it keep trying for an hour?